# Change LUKS encryption key (not passphrase) without dataloss

Tags: passphrase, luks

You can change the LUKS passphrase without dataloss, but can you also change the actual key?

I reckon you would have to re-encrypt the whole disk, but that would be acceptable to me.

**Background**

We are considering distributing a live USB with full disk encryption. But that means that even if you change the passphrase, I will still be able to get the secret key if I got a copy of the original live USB.

So the first time you use it, it should re-encrypt the whole disk with a new key (and not just a new passphrase to unlock the key).

Comment: Keep in mind that cheap USB memory sticks tend to not handle large or repeat writes terribly well (this being much more of a problem than on SSDs intended for long-term use). Consider instead treating the memory stick as a dumb read-only storage, and overlaying a ramfs for any additional data. You can have a small(ish) data partition on the memory stick too, on which you run `luksFormat` on first boot of the media, ideally as late as possible (to allow for early boot entropy collection), which files can be stored on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the `cryptsetup-reencrypt` tool, you can change almost all aspects of a luks encrypted device like, the volume key, cipher, or even encrypt a device that is not encrypted. In some distributions, you will have to download the `cryptsetup` sources and recompile with the `--enable-cryptsetup-reencrypt` option. If you are using a Red Hat based distribution, you will be interested in [this proof-of-concept](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/master/misc/dracut_90reencrypt/reencrypt.sh) dracut module at cyptsetup sources.

Running `cryptsetup-reencrypt` without parameters should be enough to start a new key being generated. But be aware that any power failure or error during the process could let data unacessible forever.

Comment: It's also worth noting that a full reencryption can take some time. Especially if the system (computer and OS) doesn't support AES-NI (or if you are using some encryption algorithm other than AES) reencrypting a reasonably sized media can take a while.

Comment: If the reencrypting is done as the very first task (i.e. before the user saves data on it), then there is no risk of dataloss - only time wasted. Good input.

Comment: But what about a power failure during the process? Even without data being written to the disk, there is always this risk. And as said by @MichaelKjörling, depending on the disk size and cryptography features of your computer, it could take a reasonable time...

Comment: Power failure is not a big problem: There will be no dataloss. They will only lose the distributed information which they can get again. The time issue can be mitigated by setting expectations: "The first time you boot this, do it before you go to bed - it will be cooked and ready the next morning".